# Pandas Read Excel ,usecol function

Tags: pandas

new to python

reading an excel file:

```
 dflist = pd.read_excel(f, sheet_name=None, header=None, usecols = 
[col]).items()
```

and variable value of "col" is as below:

```
col = ["B,C,E,F,G,H"]
```

but i am receiving an error as below:

> ValueError: 'usecols' must either be list-like of all strings, all
>   unicode, all integers or a callable.

please advise with the write syntax.

much appreciated

thanks
Sukhwant

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
col = ['B', 'C', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']
dflist = pd.read_excel(f, sheet_name=None, usecols = col)
```

It is the `header=None` that is stripping off the column names so that `usecols` is not able to use it.

Comment: same error as above after removing the header =none

Comment: Are you sure of the column names in the excel file contains those in the col list?

Comment: i changed the col = "B,C,E,F,G,H" and it worked. thanks for all your suggestions